# Python-like operator overloading in Swift

Tags: python, swift, operator-overloading

I'm getting started with Swift. My previous programming background is mostly Python, so I tend to search for Pythonic ways of coding in Swift, luckily it's partly inspired by Python. In Python there is a very powerful way to overload operators in your classes by using special methods. I know we can overload operators in Swift by defining a function in a certain name space, where we want that special behavior, but I haven't found a way to overload operators class-wise.

Edit - adding an example.

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):  # Initializing a vector of random size
        self.vector = tuple(args)

    def __len__(self):  # This sources the data to the built-in len() function
        return len(self.vector)

    def __getitem__(self, i):  # Overloads [ ] operator
        return self.vector[i]

    def __add__(self, vector):  # Overloads + operator
        if len(self) != len(vector):
            raise ValueError("Vectors should be of equal length")
        return tuple([self.vector[i] + vector[i] for i in xrange(len(self))])


a, b = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4), Vector(2, 3, 4, 5)  # My modified tuples

print(a + b)  # this operation is affected
print((1, 2, 3, 4) + (2, 3, 4, 5))  # this is not, since these are standard tuples
```

Output:

```
(3, 5, 7, 9) 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Here I have just overloaded +, by defining the **add** method, and [], by defining the **getitem** method. The class could've inherited the [] behavior from the tuple type in Python, as well as the initializer, but I made it all manually to provide more detail. Since the overloading is incapsulated in the class, it doesn't affect general operator behavior, since all types and classes define their own special methods.

Comment: So maybe you whisper the Swift gurus how it's done in Python.

Comment: Generally speaking operator overloads in Swift are always global.  The closest you could do is to create type-specific operator overloads.  Also, as Thomas indicates, you're more likely to get a useful answer if you provide all the relevant information.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I've just added an example.

Comment: @David There is an example now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of different operators that get overridden using different mechanisms.  The equivalent of `__getitem__` is to override `subscript`  To override plus, you need to implement `func +` in the global space, together you wind up with:

```
class Vector<T> {
    let vector : [T]

    init(values:[T]) {
        vector = values
    }

    subscript(index:Int) -> T {
        get {
            return vector[index]
        }
    }

    func len() -> Int {
        return vector.count
    }
}

protocol Addable {
    func +(lhs:Self, rhs:Self) -> Self
}

func + <T:Addable>(left:Vector<T>, right:Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
    var result = [T]()

    assert(left.len() == right.len(), "vectors should be of equal length")
    for i in 0 ..< left.len() {
        result.append( left[i] + right[i] )
    }

    return Vector(values: result)
}
```

Note that I've implemented it as a generic, hence the  scattered around.  You'll also need to indicate that whatever data type you use it with implements the Addable protocol.  That's as simple as:

```
extension Int : Addable {}
```

I might also point out that there's not really a whole lot of benefit here to your Vector class that isn't available through the standard array class and overriding operators, which would look like:

```
func + <T:Addable>(left:Array<T>, right:Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    var result = [T]()

    assert(left.len() == right.len(), "vectors should be of equal length")
    for i in 0 ..< left.len() {
        result.append( left[i] + right[i] )
    }

    return result
}
```

In either case, you could easily perform vector math on either an Array or a Vector using the inline `+` operator.

Comment: Vector class, hence the vectorized sum operation, was just the first example my mind baked. So, If I get it right I can overload the same operator as many times as I want it in a single piece of code as long as all the overloading functions have different type inference?

Comment: Yep.  Operator overloading is subject to all the normal rules of swift function overloads, so they must differ either in parameter count and/or type, or in result type.